# Mobile location tracking on Google maps

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, mobile

I need to develop a feature for one of my website by which user can track any mobile number on Google maps just like the link below.

Go o the following link and enter the **9810098109** number in textbox to find its location on map.

http://wwwa.way2sms.com/jsp/LocateMobile.jsp

I want to know either this page is using a third party tool to get the latitude and longitude along with service provider and draw the map accordingly or its some sort of feature provided by Google ?

Is there any freeware services to get this done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know any service allows to get user´s location from msisdn. But in some countries you can use [HLR look-up](http://www.google.com/search?q=HLR+look-up) for getting MSC and so you can localize to user nearly. Please if you find some, share it.

Comment: Thanks! fravelgue. your answer is very near to what i required. We are looking for some free service and need it for India only. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

Check Google maps API for markes http://code.google.com/intl/en-Us/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Markers.

Comment: Karel! Google have well written documentation of its map API's. Issue is to locate the latitude and longitude or city/country of user. If we have this information we can easily create a map for location.