# How to determine location of user/phone using plain SMS?

Tags: mobile, sms, geolocation, gps

how to know user location via sms from server without any applications installed in mobile

Comment: I'm sure you could imagine how quickly this could be abused if it were possible.

Comment: Not exactly, but maybe this could help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719600/mobile-location-tracking-on-google-maps/2720535#2720535

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. This will never be possible.

Comment: Definately  it won't ever be possible. text and voice are witihn operators' province and no one can ever barge in to it.

Comment: Protocols and laws change. The phones (and presumably the providers) have access to this information. Technically, it's all there, there's just nothing connecting the dots (thankfully). Noone can 'barge into it' as you put it, but they could still potentially provide this information through some scheme... Thankfully I don't have a mobile.

Comment: It's called LBS (Location Based Services) and yes it exists very much so outside of the US and has started to grow within the US on all smartphone devices

Answer (score 2):

Get the user to type their postcode/zipcode etc in the SMS, then detect and parse it at the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Location Based Services (LBS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-based_service)